# Regular expression to match lines

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I need to create a regular expression that matches the following line:

```
<iq from="Server_FQDN" to="pluto@domain.com/671372bf1e530fde" type="result" id="YmJ6ZlDhemSAbaw3"><turnServerResponse ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"><turnServer ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"/></turnServerResponse></iq>
```

In particular im interested in the fact that the line has the `turnServerResponse` tag and the strings `username="removed"` and `password="removed"`. Other lines having a different value for username and password should not be taken into account.

So a line like the one below should not be taken into account, as the values for `username` and `password` are different than `"removed"`

```
<iq from="Server_FQDN" to="pluto@domain.com/671372bf1e530fde" type="result" id="YmJ6ZlDhemSAbaw3"><turnServerResponse ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="aaa" password="bbb" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"><turnServer ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="aaa" password="bbb" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"/></turnServerResponse></iq>
```

Comment: Have u tried grouping and optional regex patterns ?

As title says you want to match lines, by default the regex search of first line. to include searching of multiple line you must add `M` flag

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if string.find('turnServerResponse')>0 and \
   string.find('username="removed"')>0 and \
   string.find('password="removed"')>0:
    doSomething()
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it following way:

```
import re
txt = '''something
<iq from="Server_FQDN" to="pluto@domain.com/671372bf1e530fde" type="result" id="YmJ6ZlDhemSAbaw3"><turnServerResponse ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"><turnServer ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"/></turnServerResponse></iq>
something
<iq from="Server_FQDN" to="pluto@domain.com/671372bf1e530fde" type="result" id="YmJ6ZlDhemSAbaw3"><turnServerResponse ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="aaa" password="bbb" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"><turnServer ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="aaa" password="bbb" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"/></turnServerResponse></iq>
something'''
lines = re.findall(r'^.*?<turnServerResponse.*?username="removed" password="removed".*$',txt,re.M)
print(lines) #list of found lines
```

Output:

```
['<iq from="Server_FQDN" to="pluto@domain.com/671372bf1e530fde" type="result" id="YmJ6ZlDhemSAbaw3"><turnServerResponse ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"><turnServer ip="1.1.1.1" port="3478" username="removed" password="removed" guid="f72d4f2f-e3f9-4ae9-b91f-c651280635aa"/></turnServerResponse></iq>']
```

Explanation:
Third argument of `re.findall` means that `^` and `$` denotes start and end of line respectively. Pattern means that I am looking for line containing `<turnServerResponse` followed by `username="removed" password="removed"` possibly with some characters between them.

Disclaimer:
Note that my method will catch *all* lines which have `username="removed" password="removed"` *after* `<turnServerResponse`, even if first one will occur *outside* `turnServerResponse` tag. However in your use-case this might be irrelevant (such situation impossible), so you have to examine yourself if described situation is possible in your usage.